# GoogleApiClient: onConnectionFailed:ConnectionResult{statusCode=RESOLUTION_REQUIRED

Tags: android, google-api-client

**EDIT:** It is working perfectly fine on my tablet and another phone. So the issue is related to the device. Any ideas? I already reinstalled all google play related apps multiple times with no success :/

When I try to connect the `GoogleApiClient` I always get

```
onConnectionFailed:ConnectionResult{statusCode=RESOLUTION_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{13c5b37: android.os.BinderProxy@e07c8a4}, message=null}
```

When I run

```
connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_RESOLUTION);
```

the `Intent` data is `null`.

I'm pretty lost here what is going wrong here and what `RESOLUTION_REQUIRED` actually means in this context.

Maybe this helps: If I try the same with the `Drive.API` I get a `SIGN_IN_REQUIRED` error which seems to be a much more common error.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

```
package com.some.domain.signin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;

import com.some.domain.activity.MainActivity;
import com.some.domain.application.ApplicationClass;



public class GoogleSignInActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

    private static final String TAG = "T1_GSignInActivity";
    private static final int RC_RESOLUTION = 9002;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "GoogleSignInActivity");

        setupGoogleClient();
    }

    public static GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    public void setupGoogleClient() {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .build();

        ApplicationClass.getInstance().setGoogleClient(googleApiClient);
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_RESOLUTION){
            startNextActivity();
        }

    }

    private void startNextActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connection failed:\n" + connectionResult.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        try {
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_RESOLUTION);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connection Suspended.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what you are trying

Comment: I want to use the Games.Leaderboards API. For this to work I need to request the Games.API.

Comment: have i import BasicSamples lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so after I struggled for like two days it turns out I got it fixed by reinstalling the google play services and the google play store. I came to realize this after I got the program run on two different devices without issues...

Also ensure the following:

**Google API:**     I registered my debug and my release certificate as Open Auth2 (SHA-1)

**Google Play:**        I connected the game in the "PlayServices" with the package name of my game

**Google-Services.json:**   Is copied into the app folder and contains all my certificates (SHA-1)

**Tester:**         I'm registered as tester

Answer (score 0):

please import `Module` Project `BaseGameUtils` in your project

also added in `gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
    // ...
}
```

[Refer link](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init)

[BaseGameUtils librarie link](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils)

Comment: Could you explain how this could solve my issue? I took your hint and added this project but I still have the same issue :/